# how to know what tile i touched in a isometric tiledmap?

Tags: android, libgdx, isometric, tiled

I am doing a game for class in isometric perspective. I am using libgdx and a map made with tiled(tmx), I have spent the two last weeks looking for information but cant find the way of knowing what tile I am clicking in the map.I have seen many pages saying that i have to turn the screen coordinates into coordinates on the map, but it doesnt work. Tiles are 64x32.

I have one actor for the map and a table for the logic of the screen.

this de actor:

```
public class ActorMapa extends Actor{


Game juego;

//elementos del mapa
TiledMap mapa;
IsometricTiledMapRenderer mapRender;
OrthographicCamera camara;

public ActorMapa(Game juego, OrthographicCamera camara) {
    this.juego= juego;
    this.camara= camara;

    //instancio el mapa
    mapa = new TmxMapLoader().load("data/mapa_plano.tmx");

    //le indico la escala al mapa
    mapRender = new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(mapa);


}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camara.combined);
    mapRender.setView(camara);
    mapRender.render();
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
}

// Convert the parsed coordinates back to map coordinates
public Vector2 convertScreenToMapCoordinates(float x, float y,
        int tileWidth, int tileHeight) {

    Vector2 result = new Vector2();

    result.x = x / tileWidth;
    result.y = y / tileHeight;

    return result;
}

public Vector2 convertMapToIsometricCoordinates(float mapX, float mapY,
        int tileWidth, int tileHeight) {
    Vector2 result = new Vector2();

    result.x = (mapX - mapY) * (tileWidth / 2);
    result.y = (mapX + mapY) * (tileHeight / 2);

    return result;
}
```

}

And I put this in de act metod of the table:

```
camara.unproject(camara.position);
    pos1.set(mapa.convertScreenToMapCoordinates(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),64,32));  
    pos2.set(mapa.convertMapToIsometricCoordinates(pos1.x, pos1.y, 64, 32));
```

Comment: Have a look at this explanation: http://clintbellanger.net/articles/isometric_math/

Comment: you will 100% have "to turn the screen coordinates into coordinates on the map" you must be doing something wrong. please post your code

Comment: I have put the code in the question